# If (G/N)/(H/N) abelian. Then H normal in G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $N\leq H\leq G$ be two subgroups of $G$ and $N\unlhd G$. Assume $H/N\unlhd G/N$. What condition(s) on $\frac{G/N}{H/N}$ to guarantee that $H\unlhd G$?

**Edit:** If $\frac{G/N}{H/N}$ is abelian. Does that imply  $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: $N$ must be  normal in $G$, not only in $H$.

Comment: oh yes, I will edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lattice Isomorphism Theorem tells us there is a correspondence between normal subgroups of the quotient group and the original group. That is, $H/N\unlhd G/N$ if and only if $H\unlhd G$, assuming the quotient is well-defined. So you should not need any other conditions.